# Select Every One not just first

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, google-tag-manager

I'm working on a custom java script variable for tag manager to track the navigation of my page. The script is only working for the very first element of the kind because of document.queryselect. document.queryselectAll is naturally not solving the problem. It would be great if you could help me:

```
function(){
   var elem = {{Click Element}};
   var menu = document.querySelector("ul.nav.meta-nav.justify-content-end");
   if(menu.contains(elem)){
     return "nav_header";
   };
var menu = document.querySelector("div.product-item");
   if(menu.contains(elem)){
     return "itemlist";
   };
var menu = document.querySelector("a.btn");
   if(menu.contains(elem)){
     return "cta_button";
   };
var menu = document.querySelector("footer.footer*");
   if(menu.contains(elem)){
     return "footer";
    }
   return "other";
}
```

Comment: Why is `querySelectorAll` not solving the issue?

Answer (score 1):

`Element.querySelectorAll()` returns a NodeList. It's like an array. So a typical usage would be:

```
var elem = {{Click Element}};
document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(function(el) {
  if (el.contains(elem)) {
    return el.getAttribute("data-something");
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function(){
  var elem = {{Click Element}};
  var type = "other"

  var selectors = {
    "ul.nav.meta-nav.justify-content-end" : "nav_header",
    "div.product-item" : "itemlist",
    "a.btn" : "cta_button",
    "footer.footer *"   : "footer"
  }

  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(selectors)) {
    var domMenu = document.querySelector(key)
    if(domMenu && domMenu.contains(elem)){
       type = value
     };
  }

  return type;
}
```

Can not test from my end but it might work.

Just make sure the selectors is good and the click element should not fall into more than one selectors.

Comment: Preview Mode does not load because "Parse error. primary expression expected", 1st row, 4th character

Comment: sorry I forgot there should be wrap by a function. Updated